# running powershell Script in Visual Studio pre build event

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

wrote a simple code by  powershell
I am creating a file xml with some program settings
I want to run it before  build desktop software
Get this error exited with code 1

[image]

[image]

in Visual Studio pre build event

```
 powershell.exe $(ProjectDir)Script1.ps1
```

I thought it was from the wrong code. I simplified the code. However I get the same error

```
 write-Host 'test'
 exit 0
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: First step would be to look at the output window (or running the build from the command line) to see what error is given.

Comment: ExecutionPolicy maybe? Does it work when you call it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Script.ps1 indeed exists in your project directory, try surrounding the arg with double-quotes and precede it with -File.

```
powershell.exe -File "$(ProjectDir)Script1.ps1"
```